# How to manipulate my JSON Data in my HTML ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs, json, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my Javascript

```
    var app = angular.module('phonebook', []);

    app.controller('userController', function($scope){

    $scope.users =[{"user_id":"16","first_name":"Telecare","last_name":"Jonathan","mobile":"09069651698","address":"USA"},
                   {"user_id":"15","first_name":"Alex ","last_name":"Mitchell","mobile":"09069651698","address":"Canada"}];

    });
```

This is my HTML

```
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <div>
          <tr ng-controller="userController" ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{users[user_id]}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </div>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Its giving me null values even I put {{users.user_id}} I just need to know how to manipulate my JSON Data to my table. Any help im new in Angular. thanks

Comment: You need to access `user` not `users`...

Comment: {{user.user_id}} still not working

Comment: {{user[user_id]}} still not working with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `ng-controller` in an element different from ng-repeat, you might be repeating the `ng-controller` directive for each row. `ng-repeat` has a priority of 1000, higher than `ng-controller`'s 500 priority, so the scope is not initialized when it compiles.

```
<div ng-controller="userController">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
...
```

**UPDATE**
Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7zhd0xqz/

**UPDATE 2**
Fiddle with table: https://jsfiddle.net/7zhd0xqz/1/

**UPDATE 3**
For some reason it is not working when setting it on a div inside the `tbody` tag, I moved the `ng-app` to `table` and `ng-controller` to `tbody` and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/qdckogbr/1/

Comment: Also, what ElendilTheTall 3 said, you need to use `user`, and if you want to use the bracket notation, make sure to include the single quotes `user['user_id']`

Comment: <div ng-app="phonebook" ng-controller="userController">
                <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                  <td>{{user.user_id}}</td> and this happens http://prntscr.com/a880ib

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see that it works in the list but it does now work in the table.

Comment: Try separating the ng-app and ng-controller as well, like in the fiddle. Also make sure you're including angularJS and your JS files in index.html, if interpolation doesn't work usually is because of some issue loading a module. If the browsers console shows any error please post it.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Solved! (y) Cheers

Comment: I just need to put wrap my table not just the tr but the whole table (y) thanks my mistake.

Comment: Since your problem is solved, please mark the answer you consider appropiate as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your example above, inside the ng-repeat block you are referencing the collection itself and not the element you want to read. In your ng-repeat tag you are defining the collection you want to iterate over and the name of the current element:

```
ng-repeat="<name of element> in <collection>"
```

in your case, this is:

```
ng-repeat="user in users"
```

Within your ng-repeat if you want to access the properties of the each element as you iterate over the collection you need to reference it by element name you specify. So in this case you want to use "user":

```
<tr ng-controller="userController" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{ user.user_id }}</td>
</tr>
```

**Edit:** Also have you defined ng-app anywhere in your markup? You have created the angular app but you also need to wrap your ng-controller inside an element with the ng-app tag.

```
<div ng-app="myAngularApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{ user.user_id }} </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have  Json array when you Looped one object will be looped at a
>   time which you already Know.
>
> i see that you are not aware of using populating Json values while
>   Using Loop

Example:-

```
 $scope.users =[{"user_id":"16","first_name":"Telecare","last_name":"Jonathan","mobile":"09069651698","address":"USA"},
                {"user_id":"15","first_name":"Alex ","last_name":"Mitchell","mobile":"09069651698","address":"Canada"}];
```

> Use dot notation to populate object values like user.last_name that's
>   the trick read more about json
>
> Working Plunker here:-

https://plnkr.co/edit/froWFsOeyYo1qfvAmtGH?p=preview